# Cannot cast FrameLayout to LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, navigation-drawer

I created my own DrawerLayout here is the XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/white"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Instead of `FrameLayout` like you get by default I chose `LinearLayout` because it allows me to set margins/paddings and automatically adding elements bellow each other. Anyhow when I call:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
```

I get an exception saying cannot cast from `FrameLayout` to `LinearLayout` but I don't have `LinearLayout` defined anywhere.

Comment: there might another layout with same name try to rename content to ll_content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stumbled on an interesting quirk on how Android creates Layouts.

The top-most layout is a FrameLayout that the system puts your layout in to. Its id is `android.R.id.content`. You probably importing the `android.R` file into your app so you're referencing `android.R.id.content` instead of your project's `R` file which would have the correct ID.

Comment: This shouldn't be true. The chances of the int defined as `android.R.id.content` coinciding with `R.id.content` are very low. They are separate ids.

Comment: There's also a chance he imported the `android.R` file rather than than project's `R` file which means it'll reference the root view.

Comment: @DeeV Your answer right now implies that the system `content` and the developer defined `content` are the same. Your last comment is a much better addition to your answer. Also, yes, `R.id.content` stays constant no matter how many times you use it. *However* unless you combine two layouts each containing a view with `R.id.content` there is no issue.

Comment: @A-C You're right. I was thinking it would re-use the default value of `R.id.content` because it already exists, but realized that doesn't make sense. It doesn't exist within the context of the app, so it's more likely he just imported the wrong R file. I shouldn't be answering so early in the morning.